# Why does BitBucket not show all characters in the source code?

Tags: bitbucket

I have the following source code:

```
static void UpdateNameAssignHistXML(CString strExistingName, CString strReplacementName = _T("¬DELETED¬"));
static void UpdateNameAssignHistXML(tinyxml2::XMLElement* element, CString strExistingName, CString strReplacementName);
static void DeleteNameFromAssignHistMAP(CString strName, CMapStringToPtr* pMapStrPtrHist);
```

Note that I use the character ¬ ???

Well, online, using Microsoft Edge, this looks like:

[image: On Bitbucket]

They show as a little question mark symbol.

Why?

Comment: this is usually a charset problem: [how to set the text encoding?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/15277413/how-to-set-the-text-encoding)

Comment: @rala I just checked my files. They are ANSI. But they view OK on my PC. You think I need to change the encoding for these characters to display online?

Comment: it was my first thought. as you see in my link it is UTF8 and based on what I learned at school: I think yes

Comment: @rala I will try tomorrow 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong display of characters is in general a *wrong* charset.
Bitbucket uses UTF8 and if you have a different one some characters may look strange or different.
[Bitbucket does not allow to change the charset yet](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/15277413/how-to-set-the-text-encoding) and UTF8 is supported since HTML4 - so many pages use it because of the amount of characters, ... .

[Here is a table which displays the differences.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) Even if it is available in both it can have a different code. *(In this table is all UTF8 I guess so everything looks fine.)*

<s>I created a test snipped which shows the symbol is showing.</s> *(removed)*